# Emacs Support for DocBook5 and XSLT

Tags: xslt, emacs, xsl-fo, docbook

I am just starting out with Emacs for creating DocBook5 documents. (*Because some vendors who offered free editions of their XML authoring software have now ceased to do so. For example, Syntext Serna Community Edition and XMLMind XML Editor Personal Edition.*)

There appear to be several different packages (modes?) for creating XML documents, transforming XML files using XSLT stylesheets, and so on.

However, each of them is available from a different site, the last version seems to have been created sometime between 2002 and 2008, and it is not clear which version of XML, XSLT etc. is being supported.

It is also not clear whether these packages can all inter-operate to successfully create and transform a DocBook5 document into, say, a PDF, which is what I want to do.

**Is there something I have missed?**

**I would be greatly helped if I am given a list of *packages* to *install* to get DocBook5 authoring and transforming working in Emacs.**

However, all advice would be useful to me, as I am a complete *newbie* to Emacs.

Comment: @wvxvw: There are XSL(T) stylesheets and there are various kinds of XML schemas (such as RELAX NG and W3C XML Schema). But what you mean by "XSL schema"?

Answer (score 0):

This package contains an Emacs major mode for editing XSL stylesheets.
The xslide home page is http://www.menteith.com/xslide/

http://www.lysator.liu.se/~lenst/about_psgml/

Beside of nxml already mentioned these both packages worked well for me.
Some Emacs Lisp to tweak occasionally seems useful though - not sure if that's the right stuff for beginners.